# Limiting decimal places of coordinate values in GEOJSON file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson

Using "QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour", I try to convert a vector layer into GEOJSON file using "Save As" sub menu. I get the GEOJSON  file, but the coordinates of points have values up to 15 decimal places.

How can I round off the values at the desired number of decimal places?

Answer (score 12):

It's very easy to limit the coordinates when exporting GeoJson, as QGIS just uses the ogr2ogr program for the export, and it allows you to pass in additional parameters when you save the file. Here's a pic:

[image]

That will ensure only 2 decimal places in the coordinates.

Comment: Newer Qgis versions have this option.

Comment: Just to round up @chrismarx question. You can also do it by the command line by adding a creation option to your ogr2ogr statement: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dsco "COORDINATE_PRECISION=6" output.json input.shp -progress`

Comment: @Valentin - must use -lco, not -dsco in ogr2ogr.\\
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=6`

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if it is possible to limit the number of the coordinates' values when you save a  vector layer as a GeoJSON file, using QGIS, but I'll show you an alternative way using a simple (but powerful) text editor: `Notepad++`.

Of course, you can use any similar software you like, only assure yourself it can perform `search an replace using regular expressions`.

Assuming you have already the GeoJSON file, just open it using Notepad++:

[image]

Then go to `Search > Replace` and use these expressions:

in the **Find what** field:

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})([0-9]+)
```

and in the **Replace with** field:

```
\1
```

[image]

(Remember that `Regular expression` must be checked)

This is the result after pressing `Replace all`:

[image]

If you want a different number of decimals just replace `{2}` with the new desired value:

[image]

Comment: Very tricky way of solving a problem. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: As highlighted by another user (in an aswer), it is worthwhile to note that this method does not round off but truncate the decimals.